# Qt Regex check for special characters

Tags: regex, qt

I'm trying to check for special characters. I tried:

```
QString test;
test = "Hello";
QRegExp re("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
if (!re.exactMatch(test))
{
   log("False");
}
```

Which returns False

Also

```
int icount = test.count(QRegExp("[!@#$%^&()_+]"));
```

Which returns > 0

I don't know what am I doing wrong!

What I need is to know if a QString contains any other character than the valid: A-Z,a-z,0-9

Comment: your pattern could only match one single (non-letter) character, so if it matches the "h" in "hello", that isn't an "exact" match, it's partial....right?  maybe `[...]+` ?

Comment: Also the new QRegularExpression is faster and recommended for new code.

Comment: Quicker way to test your patterns: https://regexr.com/  (there are others also). Once it works there, it will work in Qt (just remember to double up any `\\` in the C++ version).

Answer (score 1):

Try `QRegExp::indexIn()`

```
QRegExp re("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
if (re.indexIn("Hello") < 0)
   qDebug() << "No special chars";
else
   qDebug() << "Found at least one special char";

if (re.indexIn("Hello.") < 0)
   qDebug() << "No special chars";
else
   qDebug() << "Found at least one special char";
```

Output:

```
No special chars
Found at least one special char
```